# How to make Spring batch play nice in Java EE container

Tags: java, spring-batch, websphere-8

I am trying to use Spring Batch in a Java EE container (Websphere 8.0)
I got it working so far, but I'd like it to use a container-provided datasource and transaction manager. (I am using a derby database instead of the default hsql-db)

I copied the baseContext.xml from the spring-batch-core.jar to my classpath, and changed the beans for dataSource and transactionManager. (see below)

It seems to work as far as it seems to be able to start a transaction and access the database, but then it fails with a timeout ("could not obtain IDENTITY value").

Has anyone managed to use a Java EE dataSource with spring batch? I could find nothing online, and the spring batch documentation does not even contain the word "JEE".

This is my adapted baseContext.jar. The original bean definitions for dataSource and transaction manager have been comented out:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.1.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd">

    <tx:jta-transaction-manager />

    <jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="jbatchSampleDB" expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource" lookup-on-startup="true" cache="true" />

    <batch:job-repository data-source="dataSource" id="jobRepository"
        transaction-manager="transactionManager" table-prefix="${batch.table.prefix}"/>

    <bean id="jobLauncher" class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
        <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="batchJobOperator" class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobOperator">
        <property name="jobExplorer" ref="jobExplorer"/>
        <property name="jobLauncher" ref="jobLauncher"/>
        <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository"/>
        <property name="jobRegistry" ref="jobRegistry"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jobExplorer" class="org.springframework.batch.core.explore.support.JobExplorerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>

    <!--  bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${batch.jdbc.driver}" />
        <property name="url" value="${batch.jdbc.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${batch.jdbc.user}" />
        <property name="password" value="${batch.jdbc.password}" />
        <property name="testWhileIdle" value="${batch.jdbc.testWhileIdle}"/>
        <property name="validationQuery" value="${batch.jdbc.validationQuery}"/>
    </bean -->

    <!--  bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean -->

    <!--  Initialise the database if enabled: -->
    <jdbc:initialize-database data-source="dataSource" enabled="${batch.data.source.init}" ignore-failures="DROPS">
        <jdbc:script location="${batch.drop.script}"/>
        <jdbc:script location="${batch.schema.script}"/>
    </jdbc:initialize-database>

    <bean id="jobParametersConverter" class="org.springframework.batch.core.jsr.JsrJobParametersConverter">
        <constructor-arg ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jobRegistry" class="org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.support.MapJobRegistry"/>

    <bean id="placeholderProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:batch-${ENVIRONMENT:derby}.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE" />
        <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true" />
        <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="false" />
        <property name="order" value="1" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

These are the errors I am getting:

```
[21.10.14 11:00:27:961 CEST] 0000002a WSRdbXaResour E   DSRA0302E:  XAException occurred.  Error code is: XA_RBTIMEOUT (106).  Exception is: XA_RBTIMEOUT : Fehler beim Ausführen von XAResource.end(). Der Server hat Folgendes zurückgegeben: XA_RBTIMEOUT
[21.10.14 11:00:28:050 CEST] 0000002a FfdcProvider  W com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident emitted on C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\logs\ffdc\server1_df9126ba_14.10.21_11.00.27.962173746269389570625.txt com.ibm.ejs.j2c.XATransactionWrapper.end 417
[21.10.14 11:00:28:050 CEST] 0000002a XATransaction E   J2CA0027E: An exception occurred while invoking end on an XA Resource Adapter from DataSource jbatchSampleDB, within transaction ID {XidImpl: formatId(57415344), gtrid_length(36), bqual_length(54),
data(0000014931eeb4a80000000247b5d940930c671bd3532a7d4a65bea7645c1bb4338195240000014931eeb4a80000000247b5d940930c671bd3532a7d4a65bea7645c1bb433819524000000010000000000000000000000000001)} : org.apache.derby.client.am.XaException: XA_RBTIMEOUT : Fehler beim Ausführen von XAResource.end(). Der Server hat Folgendes zurückgegeben: XA_RBTIMEOUT
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetXAResource.throwXAException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetXAResource.end(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.WSRdbXaResourceImpl.end(WSRdbXaResourceImpl.java:623)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.XATransactionWrapper.end(XATransactionWrapper.java:608)
    at com.ibm.ws.Transaction.JTA.JTAResourceBase.end(JTAResourceBase.java:254)
    at com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.RegisteredResources.sendEnd(RegisteredResources.java:1152)
    at com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.RegisteredResources.distributeEnd(RegisteredResources.java:1128)
    at com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.TransactionImpl.internalRollback(TransactionImpl.java:1992)
    at com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.TransactionImpl.internalRollback(TransactionImpl.java:1957)
    at com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.TransactionImpl.rollback(TransactionImpl.java:1359)
    at com.ibm.ws.tx.jta.TransactionImpl.rollback(TransactionImpl.java:3608)
    at com.ibm.ws.tx.jta.TranManagerImpl.rollback(TranManagerImpl.java:478)
    at com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.TranManagerSet.rollback(TranManagerSet.java:206)
    at com.ibm.ws.uow.UOWManagerImpl.uowRollback(UOWManagerImpl.java:829)
    at com.ibm.ws.uow.EmbeddableUOWManagerImpl.uowEnd(EmbeddableUOWManagerImpl.java:855)
    at com.ibm.ws.uow.UOWManagerImpl.uowEnd(UOWManagerImpl.java:777)
    at com.ibm.ws.uow.EmbeddableUOWManagerImpl.runUnderNewUOW(EmbeddableUOWManagerImpl.java:814)
    at com.ibm.ws.uow.EmbeddableUOWManagerImpl.runUnderUOW(EmbeddableUOWManagerImpl.java:366)
    at org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebSphereUowTransactionManager.execute(WebSphereUowTransactionManager.java:290)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:279)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.AbstractJobRepositoryFactoryBean$1.invoke(AbstractJobRepositoryFactoryBean.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy52.createJobInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.jsr.launch.JsrJobOperator.start(JsrJobOperator.java:630)
    at vwg.jbatchtest.ejb.BatchMonitorEJB.startJob(BatchMonitorEJB.java:32)
    at vwg.jbatchtest.ejb.EJSLocalNSFBatchMonitorEJB_88c81e47.startJob(EJSLocalNSFBatchMonitorEJB_88c81e47.java)
    at vwg.jbatchtest.ui.controller.BatchMonitorUIController.getStatus(BatchMonitorUIController.java:19)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at org.apache.webbeans.intercept.InterceptorHandler.invoke(InterceptorHandler.java:297)
    at org.apache.webbeans.intercept.NormalScopedBeanInterceptorHandler.invoke(NormalScopedBeanInterceptorHandler.java:98)
    at vwg.jbatchtest.ui.controller.BatchMonitorUIController_$$_javassist_1.getStatus(BatchMonitorUIController_$$_javassist_1.java)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:91)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:55)
    at org.apache.myfaces.el.unified.resolver.FacesCompositeELResolver.getValue(FacesCompositeELResolver.java:142)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:174)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:283)
    at org.apache.webbeans.el.WrappedValueExpression.getValue(WrappedValueExpression.java:68)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:85)
    at javax.faces.component._DeltaStateHelper.eval(_DeltaStateHelper.java:243)
    at javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:71)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.renderkit.RendererUtils.getValue(RendererUtils.java:343)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.renderkit.RendererUtils.getStringValue(RendererUtils.java:295)
    at org.apache.myfaces.renderkit.html.HtmlLabelRenderer.encodeBegin(HtmlLabelRenderer.java:126)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeBegin(UIComponentBase.java:502)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:613)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:622)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.renderView(FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.java:1364)
    at org.apache.myfaces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:263)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:59)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RenderResponseExecutor.execute(RenderResponseExecutor.java:85)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:240)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:191)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1230)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:779)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:478)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1071)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.dispatch(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:1385)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:194)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor.handleRequest(DefaultExtensionProcessor.java:654)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1071)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3774)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:981)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:453)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:515)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:306)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:277)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1702)
Caused by: org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException: Fehler beim Ausführen von XAResource.end(). Der Server hat Folgendes zurückgegeben: XA_RBTIMEOUT
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetXAResource.xaRetValErrorAccumSQL(Unknown Source)
    ... 89 more
.
[21.10.14 11:00:28:087 CEST] 0000002a FfdcProvider  W com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident emitted on C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\logs\ffdc\server1_df9126ba_14.10.21_11.00.28.0529176547779395125373.txt com.ibm.ws.tx.jta.JTAXAResourceImpl.end 307
[21.10.14 11:00:28:088 CEST] 0000002a BusinessExcep E   CNTR0020E: EJB threw an unexpected (non-declared) exception during invocation of method "startJob" on bean "BeanId(jbatchTestAppl-EAR#jbatchTestAppl-EJB.jar#BatchMonitorEJB, 31EEAC2F-0149-4000-E000-15B00AB49C66)". Exception data: javax.batch.operations.JobStartException: org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Could not obtain IDENTITY value; nested exception is java.sql.SQLTransactionRollbackException: Eine Sperre konnte innerhalb der vorgegebenen Zeit nicht angefordert werden.
    at org.springframework.batch.core.jsr.launch.JsrJobOperator.start(JsrJobOperator.java:633)
    at vwg.jbatchtest.ejb.BatchMonitorEJB.startJob(BatchMonitorEJB.java:32)
    at vwg.jbatchtest.ejb.EJSLocalNSFBatchMonitorEJB_88c81e47.startJob(EJSLocalNSFBatchMonitorEJB_88c81e47.java)
    at vwg.jbatchtest.ui.controller.BatchMonitorUIController.getStatus(BatchMonitorUIController.java:19)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at org.apache.webbeans.intercept.InterceptorHandler.invoke(InterceptorHandler.java:297)
    at org.apache.webbeans.intercept.NormalScopedBeanInterceptorHandler.invoke(NormalScopedBeanInterceptorHandler.java:98)
    at vwg.jbatchtest.ui.controller.BatchMonitorUIController_$$_javassist_1.getStatus(BatchMonitorUIController_$$_javassist_1.java)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:91)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:55)
    at org.apache.myfaces.el.unified.resolver.FacesCompositeELResolver.getValue(FacesCompositeELResolver.java:142)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:174)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:283)
    at org.apache.webbeans.el.WrappedValueExpression.getValue(WrappedValueExpression.java:68)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:85)
    at javax.faces.component._DeltaStateHelper.eval(_DeltaStateHelper.java:243)
    at javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:71)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.renderkit.RendererUtils.getValue(RendererUtils.java:343)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.renderkit.RendererUtils.getStringValue(RendererUtils.java:295)
    at org.apache.myfaces.renderkit.html.HtmlLabelRenderer.encodeBegin(HtmlLabelRenderer.java:126)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeBegin(UIComponentBase.java:502)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:613)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:622)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.renderView(FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.java:1364)
    at org.apache.myfaces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:263)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:59)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RenderResponseExecutor.execute(RenderResponseExecutor.java:85)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:240)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:191)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1230)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:779)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:478)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1071)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.dispatch(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:1385)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:194)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor.handleRequest(DefaultExtensionProcessor.java:654)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1071)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3774)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:981)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:453)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:515)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:306)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:277)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1702)
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Could not obtain IDENTITY value; nested exception is java.sql.SQLTransactionRollbackException: Eine Sperre konnte innerhalb der vorgegebenen Zeit nicht angefordert werden.
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.incrementer.DerbyMaxValueIncrementer.getNextKey(DerbyMaxValueIncrementer.java:160)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.incrementer.AbstractDataFieldMaxValueIncrementer.nextLongValue(AbstractDataFieldMaxValueIncrementer.java:128)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcJobInstanceDao.createJobInstance(JdbcJobInstanceDao.java:108)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.createJobInstance(SimpleJobRepository.java:303)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport$1.doInTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:285)
    at org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebSphereUowTransactionManager$UOWActionAdapter.run(WebSphereUowTransactionManager.java:347)
    at com.ibm.ws.uow.EmbeddableUOWManagerImpl.runUnderNewUOW(EmbeddableUOWManagerImpl.java:787)
    at com.ibm.ws.uow.EmbeddableUOWManagerImpl.runUnderUOW(EmbeddableUOWManagerImpl.java:366)
    at org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebSphereUowTransactionManager.execute(WebSphereUowTransactionManager.java:290)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:279)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.AbstractJobRepositoryFactoryBean$1.invoke(AbstractJobRepositoryFactoryBean.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy52.createJobInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.jsr.launch.JsrJobOperator.start(JsrJobOperator.java:630)
    ... 63 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLTransactionRollbackException: Eine Sperre konnte innerhalb der vorgegebenen Zeit nicht angefordert werden.
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.Statement.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcStatement.pmiExecuteQuery(WSJdbcStatement.java:1723)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcStatement.executeQuery(WSJdbcStatement.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.incrementer.DerbyMaxValueIncrementer.getNextKey(DerbyMaxValueIncrementer.java:145)
    ... 87 more
Caused by: org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException: Eine Sperre konnte innerhalb der vorgegebenen Zeit nicht angefordert werden.
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.Statement.completeSqlca(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.parseOpenQueryError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.parseOPNQRYreply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.readOpenQuery(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.StatementReply.readOpenQuery(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatement.readOpenQuery_(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.Statement.readOpenQuery(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.Statement.flowExecute(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.Statement.executeQueryX(Unknown Source)
    ... 91 more
```

The german error message of the last few exceptions ("Eine Sperre konnte innerhalb der vorgegebenen Zeit nicht angefordert werden.") translates roughly to "A lock could not be obtained in the specified time"